# Conditional Left Join in dplyr using subset

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, conditional-operator

I'm trying to perform a conditional left join between two dataframes using dplyr. My first dataframe, df1:

```
ID  Start Date End Date
1   1-1-2000   4-1-2020
```

My second dataframe, df2:

```
ID START_DT END_DT   Name
1  2-3-2002 3-1-2020 John Smith
1  4-2-2004 4-1-2021 Karen Anderson
```

I'm trying to join on ID where Start Date > START_DT AND End Date <= END_DT

```
ID START_DT END_DT   Name        Start Date  End Date
1  2-3-2002 3-1-2020 John Smith  1-1-2000    4-1-2020
```

I've tried this which gives me an error

```
new_df <- left_join(df2, df1, by = "ID") %>%
  subset(subset(new_df, `Start Date` > START_DT & `End Date` <= END_DT))
```

I've also tried to just do the join and then subset, which gives me

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval(e, x, parent.frame()) :
  Incompatible methods (">.POSIXt", "Ops.factor") for ">"
2: In eval(e, x, parent.frame()) :
  Incompatible methods ("<=.POSIXt", "Ops.factor") for "<="
```

Comment: You've listed `subset` twice in the second to last code chunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could tell there were three issues with your code: you used `subset()` twice, referenced `new_df` in your `dplyr` pipe which is unnecessary and will cause issues, and your dates were not in R's default format.

The code below should work for you and hopefully clarify where your errors were.

```
new_df <- left_join(df2, df1, by = "ID") %>%
  subset(as.Date(Start Date, "%m-%d-%Y") > as.Date(START_DT, "%m-%d-%Y") & as.Date(End Date, "%m-%d-%Y") <= as.Date(END_DT, "%m-%d-%Y"))
```

Another alternative is to use `filter()`:

```
new_df <- left_join(df2, df1, by = "ID") %>%
  filter(as.Date(Start Date, "%m-%d-%Y") > as.Date(START_DT, "%m-%d-%Y") & as.Date(End Date, "%m-%d-%Y") <= as.Date(END_DT, "%m-%d-%Y"))
```

I hope this helps!